# EmberData Setting value prevents future autoloads of data after model save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In EmberData calling `model.save()` causes the model to be persisted via whatever adapter is in place. If the adapter returns some data (such as JSON from an API) the model is updated with that data.

I have stumbled upon a sequence where this is not true.

In a voucher system for a checkout process a `voucherCode` is entered on an `order` model. When an 'Apply' button is pressed the order is saved via `order.save()` and the voucher is thus submitted to the server.

If the voucher code is valid a `voucherValue` field is populated with a number. If the voucher code is invalid a `422` error is returned with a standard `errors` object as per http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html

Now, here is where things go awry. If a code is entered that returns a `voucherValue` of `300` a controller property calculates the discount.

```
discount: function () {
  var discount = this.get('model.voucherValue');
  // some calculation
  return discount;
}.property('model.voucherValue')
```

If, for whatever reason, the user then enters an invalid code we return an error as described above. The server removes the discount and sets the `voucherValue` to `0`

As the error response does not contain the updated data in the `catch` of the `save` we manually update it.

```
order.save().then(function () {

}).catch(function (error) {

  order.set('voucherValue', 0);
});
```

The `discount` `computed property` is updated as expected on setting the `voucherValue`. However, inspecting the order model shows that `order._data.voucherValue` is still the original `300` value from the first valid voucher code - as EmberData does not know this value is persisted on the server.

If we then enter a valid voucher code that returns a `voucherValue` of `300` (the same as it was originally) **the  `discount` computed property is not recalculated**.

It appears Ember is checking the returned data values against `order._data` and as there is no difference is not triggering any property recalculations.

I've tried different workarounds but have been unable to find something that works reliably.

Frustratingly there does not seem to be a reliable way to access the returned data and manually set the `voucherValue` from the returned data. Even if the returned data sets a value for `voucherValue` the following is true:

```
order.save().then(function (savedOrder) {

  savedOrder.get('voucherValue') === 0; //true

}).catch(function (error) {
  order.set('voucherValue', 0);
});
```

However, if a different voucher is entered after an invalid voucher and the `voucherValue` is different (say `450`) everything works as expected.

Is this a bug in EmberData? Is there a know workaround. I'm open to suggestions and willing to try anything before I try and reengineer how this entire system is implemented.

Comment: Please do change the wording of the title/question if you can, I know what I have put is pretty awful.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think I once had this problem... I had to change the http response code to 204 No Content I guess...

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your scenario.. You say that after trying to save a voucherValue of 300, getting an error from the server then setting voucherValue to 0 (in your catch), if you then set it to 300 again the computed property doesn't recalculate.. for me it does..

Comment: I've created a JSBin to help with this question.. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guraxu/11/edit?js,output ... this demonstrates that setting a value (e.g. 300), then clicking 'save, fail and reset' attempts to save, fails with 422 and sets voucherValue to 0 - if you then set the value to 300 again, the discount value does actually get updated..

Answer (score 0):

This bit of your code seems to be a problem:

```
order.save().then(function (savedOrder) {
  savedOrder.get('voucherValue') === 0; //true
}).catch(function (error) {
  order.set('voucherValue', 0);
});
```

The `catch` function is a proxy to the promise's catch.  However, promises normally expect a 2nd parameter to be passed to the `then` function, like this:

```
order.save().then(function (savedOrder) {
  savedOrder.get('voucherValue') === 0; //true
}, function (error) {
  order.set('voucherValue', 0);
});
```

This 2nd function represents the `reject` path of the `resolve/reject` pair used by the `Promise`. See: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_save

Comment: From my reading of the documentation for Promises using a `catch` is functionally equivalent to passing the `reject` handler as a second argument to `then` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html#method_catch

Comment: So did you try my suggestion or are you going strictly by your interpretation of the docs?

Comment: BTW, the "catch" function doc says: `catch is simply sugar for then(undefined, onRejection) which makes it the same as the catch block of a try/catch statement.`  So you are chaining a `then()` to the existing `then()` if that makes sense.  It is not functionally equivalent to passing the `reject` handler as a second argument to the first `then`

Answer (score 0):

If the server is supposed to be setting `model.voucherValue`, then you need to stop setting it on the client.  Setting it on the client can interfere with the record's intended state while Ember Data is trying to materialize it in the adapter.

I think it can be solved by changing your property definition a bit:

```
discount: function () {
  if (this.get('model.errors.length') > 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  var discount = this.get('model.voucherValue');
  // some calculation
  return discount;
}.property('model.voucherValue', 'model.errors.length')
```

Or something similar, depending on your use case.

Comment: This is something I had considered but I haven't been able to see how to use Ember's built in error system *and* return the updated value (`voucherValue = 0`) in the server response.

Comment: If there's an error on the server, then you shouldn't be returning anything to the client aside from the error.  The server's state shouldn't be pushed to the client until it becomes valid again--and you can't just make assumptions about what the values on the server will be, which is why I'm suggesting `discount` as an intermediate value that makes sense to the user.